# How to merge the changes in undofile with the current version?

Tags: undo-redo

I use [undotree](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree) to visualize the changes available in my `undofile`. Is it possible to merge a branch of the `undofile` with the current version of the file I am working on?

I am looking for something similar to merging two versions of a file in `git`.
[image: Example undo tree shown by the undotree plugin]

Comment: It looks like there is a feature request on this that has been pending since 2013. https://github.com/mbbill/undotree/issues/20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would:

1. Save the current version to disk
2. Select the version from the undo tree
3. Run the `:Diff` command

Remark: The `:Diff` command is not a standard Vim command but it is a common addition.

Here is the [version](https://gist.github.com/romainl/7198a63faffdadd741e4ae81ae6dd9e6) of @romainl:

```
function! Diff(spec)
    vertical new
    setlocal bufhidden=wipe buftype=nofile nobuflisted noswapfile
        let cmd = "++edit #"
    if len(a:spec)
        let cmd = "!git -C " .. shellescape(fnamemodify(finddir('.git', '.;'), ':p:h:h')) .. " show " .. a:spec .. ":#"
    endif
    execute "read " .. cmd
    silent 0d_
    diffthis
    wincmd p
    diffthis
endfunction

command! -nargs=? Diff call Diff(<q-args>)
```

Comment: @Matt is the solution addressing your problem. If so could you validate it using the v green button next to the arrow voting button. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: I had hoped for a more efficient approach to this matter, but it seems that no alternative exists at the moment.